# Не могу отобразить картинку. Django

Tags: html, python, django, img

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку.

Хочу отобразить картинку `glad.jpg`, но Django ее не находит.

**HTML registration.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<img src="static/glad.jpg" alt=img>
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

**Браузер**

[image: Браузер]

**Консоль браузера** 

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/glad.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

**Скрин дерева проекта**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понятия не имею почему он не работает, кучу всего перечитал/перепробовал.

Делал так же

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<img src="{%  static "glad.jpg" %} " alt="img">
```

, но его ничего не лечит. Даже pycharm видит изображение. Collectstatic делал кучу раз. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше оставить последний вариант:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<img src="{%  static "glad.jpg" %} " alt="img">
```

Немного запутанная у вас архитектура папок. Возможно вам стоит положить всю статику в какое-нибудь отдельное место и указать путь к этому месту в `STATICFILES_DIRS`, что должно решить вашу проблему.

Пример из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Почитать про статику можно [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: И будет подтягиватся из этой статической папки этот рисунок?

Comment: Статика будет подтягиваться из всех папок, указанных в `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: Заработало! СПАСИБО! 4 часа и наконец решилось! Удачи Вам!